# which approach to create browser extension that parses html and converts it into chordpro

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'd like to build a firefox extension which parses some fragements of a website that contains a song. The goal is to turn a music chord written in HTML e.g. any `<span class="beginLine">This is<span class="chord">Em<sup>7</sup></span>an example</span>` into e.g. `This is[Em7] an example` (that's chordpro formatting).

I did some tutorials on how to create firefox extensions but I have to be honest that I don't know javascript that well. All I know is that it is capable of doing so. That's why I wanted to ask you guys, what an appropriate approach would be? The song I want to parse consists of several elements described before. The goal in the end is to save the formatted song in a chordpro file (txt would also be okay).

Comment: So basically you want to create a scraper/parser. What if that website changes the HTML? Your extension will basically be broken from that point on.

Comment: Yes scraper/parser is the right word! What is a good approach for that and are there any good tutorials you can recommend? Regarding the changing structure in the future: I don’t mind right now :)

Comment: [This is your box of LEGOs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) - If you know all your pieces, and how they fit together, all it takes is to build and build and build. There are way too many tutorials online, start from any ;)

Comment: Also, please, take a [tour] (since you have not already), then know that we're expecting to see some code, therefore, when asking questions try always to provide a [mcve] of a **specific issue**. For more info read: [ask]. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a proper HTML parser like [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString), then you can easily use [Element.replaceWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) to construct the desired output

```js
const formatter = (html) => {
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
  doc.querySelectorAll(".chord").forEach(elChord => {
    elChord.replaceWith(`[${elChord.textContent}]`);
  })
  doc.querySelectorAll(".beginLine").forEach(elLine => {
    elLine.replaceWith(`${elLine.textContent}`);
  })
  return doc.body.textContent.trim().replace(/\n+\s+/g, "\n");
};


const scrapedHTML = `
  <span class="beginLine">This is <span class="chord">Em<sup>7</sup></span> an example</span>
  <span class="beginLine">and how <span class="chord">A<sup>13</sup></span> to do it?!</span>
`;
const formatted = formatter(scrapedHTML);
console.log(formatted);
```